# USB interrupt transfer lost data

Tags: android, usb, interrupt, hid

Since few days I am dealing with confusing USB problem. My Android(4.2) application should have connect with USB device which transmit/receive data using USB HID interrupt protocol. Sending data from Android to device works perfectly but I have got plenty of problems with receiving proper data. Main application based on 3 tasks: main task (UI), USB receive task and USB transmit task. USB's tasks have separate queue to insert received data (receiver) or obtain data to send (sender) which comes from main task. I try to sniff data that comes over USB (using android virtual machine and Windows USB analyzer) and everything looks fine but Android receives only zeros (sometimes receives another expected values).

Here is my reading and writting code - both works in separate Runnable instance:

```
public boolean writeRawData(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbRequest request, ByteBuffer buffer, int bufsize)
{
    if (request.queue(buffer, bufsize) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public ByteBuffer readRawData(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbRequest request, ByteBuffer buffer, int bufsize)
{
        if (request.queue(buffer, bufsize) == true)
        {
            if (connection.requestWait() == request)
            {
               //deal with received data -> almost always wrong!
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you are attempting to do with the received data? Your issue is most likely where you only have a comment.

Comment: At the moment I'm printing it out like below:
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++) System.out.println(buffer[i])